# ImportError with WinPython scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I just installed the current version of WinPython 3.7 to this directory on my PC:
`C:\WPy64-3770`.  Unfortunately, when I type `import scipy` in the IPython console I get these errors

```
import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-4363d2be0702>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy

  File "C:\WPy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
    from . import fft

  File "C:\WPy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\fft\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from ._basic import (

  File "C:\WPy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\fft\_basic.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy._lib.uarray import generate_multimethod, Dispatchable

  File "C:\WPy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\uarray.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._uarray import *

  File "C:\WPy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_uarray\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from ._backend import *

  File "C:\WPy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_uarray\_backend.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import _uarray  # type: ignore

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Would be grateful for any suggestions to resolve this issue - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see scipy import fails for WPy64-3770
https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/849